# Appearance of characters in substrings

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-search, binary-data

Given an S string of characters, write a program that responds correctly if character C appears in the substring of S that starts at position I and has length T.

entry
The S string formed of alphanumeric characters and of length at most 1,000,000. Subsequently an integer N followed by N triplets C, I, T. You can assume that 1≤N≤10,000 that 0≤I <| S | and 1≤T≤ | S | -I.

exit
For each question, a line with a 1 if the character appears in the indicated substring and 0 otherwise.

My idea was to implement a binary search but the judge that qualifies it says that it goes beyond the expected time and I do not know how to optimize it to the degree that the judge accepts my algorithm. For example, an entry could be:

```
how are you
3
h 0 3
1
o 2 5
1
a 4 4
0
```

My code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int busqcadena(char cadena[], int a[],char x,int pos,int n);

int main()
{
    char cadena[1000000]; 
    char c;
    int t = 0, i; 
    int pos, lon, a[1000000], j = 0;
    do{
        fflush(stdin);
        c = getchar();
        cadena[i++] = c;
        a[j] = j;
        j++;
    } while (c != '\n');
    cadena[ i - 1 ] = '\0'; 

    scanf("%d",&t);
    for( int k = 0; k < t; k++){
    char pa; pos = 0; lon = 0;
    scanf("%s %d %d",&pa, &pos, &lon);
    int busq3 = busqcadena(cadena,a,pa,pos,lon);
    if( busq3 != -1){
        printf("1\n");
    }else{
        printf("0\n");
    } 
}
    return 0; 
}

int busqcadena(char cadena[], int arr[],char x,int pos,int n){
    int a = 0, b = n - 1;
    while( a <= b ){
        int k = (a+b)/2;
        if( cadena[k] == x && arr[k] == pos){
            return arr[k]; 
        }
        if( arr[k] > pos ) b = k - 1;
        else a = k + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Pick one and adjust tags appropriately.

Comment: i am using C in the code

Answer (score 0):

Since you only have fixed number of characters you can calculate the count of each character starting from index `0`. Once you do that you just need to check if the count has increased for that character from `I`to  `T`. Pseudo-code follows

```
char_count = 26 # I am assuming only lower case letter, but change it if its not
max_len = 1000000  # maximum length of string
count = int[char_count][max_len]  # 2D array storing cumulative count for each character, fill with 0

# read the string s
# populate the count array
count[s[0]][0] = 1  # set count 1 for first character in S
for i=0:char_count:
    for j=1:len(s):
        if s[j] == char[i]:  # equals i-th character
            count[i][j] = count[i][j-1]+1
        else:
            count[i][j] = count[i][j-1]

# for each query do following 
for q=0:num_queries:
    if count[C][T] != count[C][I]:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```

Comment: Could the initialization be optimized by declaring `count` as `int[max_len][char_count]`, removing the `for i=0:char_count:` loop, and then just iterating over the string, first using `memcpy()` to copy the previous column to the current, and then just adding one to the approriate row in the current column.

Comment: it will still need to copy the last column. But in practice it should be faster.

Comment: That requires an array with 26 million entries (actually 36 million since OP says alphanumeric and perhaps 62 million, if input is case sensitive.) That's almost certainly too big for a stack allocation, so malloc will be needed. (I know it's pseudocode but the warning seemed pertinent.)